# How many reviews to include in Schema markup (JSON-LD) on product pages?

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld, user-reviews

We have product pages with multiple reviews. Some have 200. 300 reviews.
Obviously we do not put them all in the page html on page load - we show 5 as default. A person can hit "see more views" - 5 more will be ajax loaded, etc.

How many should we include in Schema markup (JSON-LD)?

I see some not include reviews at all - just aggregate rating. I see some people including 5-10 reviews, I saw one page including 50 reviews.
Theoretically we can include all of them (not to slow down page we can wait for DOM ready and than make data push). I just wonder if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For products, Google only pays attention to the aggregate rating.  See https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product

You tagged your question as SEO, but there is no ranking benefit from marking up your reviews.   At most you will get rating stars in the search results.

Other types of reviews you might want mark up the actual reviews.

- Job postings: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting
- Restaurants, stores, movies, or books: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review

In cases where you do mark up all the reviews, they don't all have to be on one page.   You can break the reviews into multiple pages.

Comment: Stephen, I thought so too, but than saw this recommendation:

"Review, recommended
A nested Review of the product."

Comment: they say they recommend it.

Comment: also review is generated for the product mark up in their Google Structured Data Markup Helper

Comment: But unless Google uses that information to improve your appearance in the search results there is no reason to implement the markup.   From what I can tell, Google only shows the review cards for businesses and movies, not for products.  Of course Google is going to recommend that you make it as easy as possible for them to use your data, but unless they give you a benefit for it, I'd recommend not making your data easy to take.

Answer (score 2):

I think a webpage should only be applying schema markup to the reviews that are actually on that page. Schema markup helps Google determine what content is on your page. And so applying schema markup to a page that requires a user to click "view more" in order to actually see the marked up content isn't entirely accurate as to the page's content.

Applying schema markup to content on a page that isn't actually on that page is almost like cloaking in a way. I don't know if Google will penalize that, but I don't think it's actually using the schema markup in the way that it was intended and may end up hurting you.

Let's look at an example.

Imagine there is schema markup on a page for "apples", but there is only content on that page for "cupcakes". When a user clicks on the link because of the markup in hopes to see content for "apples", but only finds a page about "cupcakes", the wrong content was served up to the user. Therefore, there shouldn't be schema markup about apples on that page, or content that is not on that page altogether.

Comment: "Applying schema markup to content on a page that isn't actually on that page is almost like cloaking in a way" agree : )